# Android 9patch image shows difference result each devices

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have two devices Nexus5 and LG G3.

In same project, nine patch image shows difference result.

This small image is the nine patch that file name is 'main_ground_bg.9.png' ->
[image]

The image is white and has gray border where top, bottom.

And results are...

Nexus 5 works well.

[image]

But LG G3 devices shows gray...

[image]

I putted the ninepatch image on 'drawable-xxhdpi' folder

and xml source is below code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<ImageView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/main_ground_bg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First of all 9-patch images mostly put on drawable folder.

Comment: upload your nine patch image also.

Comment: Nine-patch images where in 'drawable' folder it not works (http://bit.ly/1mh2p7D). and already I uploaded ninepatch image and explained it. But it's too small

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) .Use This

```
 <ImageView
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:src="@drawable/main_ground_bg" />
```

Comment: Now i changed scaleType. Check this out

Comment: It's better than fitCenter, But same result of my question. only works well in Nexus5.